# Representing data in array or collection to iterate

Tags: c#, string, class, collections

Very basic question... I have records

```
| fname | lname | designation | comment |
| a     | aa    | aaa         | aaaa    |
| b     | bb    | bbb         | bbbb    |
| c     | cc    | ccc         | cccc    |
```

I need to iterate all of these in a loop... one method is that I create a class and make array of its objects so that I could iterate through.. like this

```
class Person
{
    string fname {set; get;}
    string lname {set; get;}
    string designation {set; get;}
    string comment {set; get;}
}

Person [] person = new Person[3];

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
   person[x].fname = "asd";
}
```

Is there any other where I could make array of strings or some collection by which I don't have to make a class...

Comment: You could use `List<Tuple<string,string,string,string>>`

Comment: Why not use a class? It's the preferred way.

Comment: Unless it's for debug purposes (tuples, maps or list of arrays) and/or you use it within 20 lines of code (anonymous types)...let's make a class (and I would say _always_ use them, no excepetions)! **Why** you have to avoid them? To save few lines of code isn't a reason (otherwise your first question should be **Is C# the language I need to use?**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[c# anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) might be your choice.

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
Console.WriteLine(v.Amount + v.Message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) - although using a class has many more benefits, since it abstracts the 'Person' information appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Dictionary` class:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> records = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
records.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
records[0]["fname"] = "name";
```

Answer (score 0):

In a statically typed language it's just the way: to define new classes for your data objects (normally as a POCO).

In some other statically typed languages that got tuples right - like F# - I would say you could just use a tuple. But Tuple in C# is just a bolted on thing and makes your code ugly and hard to understand (What is e.Item1?).

Or you can go totally dynamic by using an ExpandoObject or better [ElasticObject](https://github.com/amazedsaint/ElasticObject#readme)! Because I think you've come to C# with a dynamic programming background and I think you would like that. However I discourage you from using this. Because it's in contrast with what a statically typed language is designed for.